# How to return function?

Tags: jquery

How can I return to or call back this method?

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $(".header-50").fadeIn("slow");
    $(".header-cover-right").animate({ height: "60%"} , 2000);
    $(".header-25").fadeIn("slow");
    $(".header-cover-left").animate({ height: "60%"} , 2000);
    $(".header-10").fadeIn("slow");
 }, 5000);
```

I want to change the function after 5 seconds to

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $(".header-50").fadeIn("slow");
    $(".header-cover-right").animate({ height: "100%"} , 2000);
    $(".header-25").fadeIn("slow");
    $(".header-cover-left").animate({ height: "100%"} , 2000);
    $(".header-10").fadeIn("slow");
 }, 5000);
```

... and how can I repeat this method forever?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try something like (its just and idea, you can improve it)

```
    var edit = true;

function f1() {
    alert('s1');
    edit = false;
 }


function f2() {
    alert('s2');
    edit = true;
 }

function choose()
{
    if(edit)
    {
       f1();
    }
    else
    {
       f2();
    }
}

setInterval(function(){choose();}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a recursive function?

```
function doStuff(i){

    var height = (i % 2) ? 60 : 100;

    if(i){ // from 5 seconds and onwards...

        $('.header-cover-right').animate({ height: height + 'px' } , 2000);
        // etc...
    }

    setTimeout(function(){
        doStuff(++i || 1);
    }, 5000);
}

doStuff();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7g1f2aar/2/